# How can I print nsXPIDLCString as string in c++?

Tags: c++

I am not familiar with c++. I have below object which I need to print. Please guide me how can I print that?

```
nsXPIDLCString flavorStr;
printf("step %s", flavorStr);

Error:
 warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 2 has type ‘nsXPIDLCString’ [-Wformat]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the type of `nsXPIDLCString`?  This is not a C++ thing.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/nsXPIDLCString Says you get the desired `char*` from `get()`.

Comment: What does `cout << flavorString << endl;` do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
printf("step %s", flavorStr.get());
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/nsXPIDLCString#get

Sidenote: Come. On. This took me 10 seconds at google to find.